# Beautiful Soup not Scraping all the visible website Data (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

My issue is that I'm trying to scrape a bunch of different websites to find all visible text to download to a .txt file -- unfortunately I'm not getting all the possible text I can from these websites.  I have posted a working example of my code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter


urls = ['https://www304.americanexpress.com/credit-card/compare']

with open('thisisanew.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    for url in urls:
        website = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content)
        text = [''.join(s.findAll(text=True))for s in soup.findAll('p')]
        for item in text:
            print(item, file=outfile)
```

If you test out this code, all you get is the following  data --

```
Ratings & Reviews for this card are currently not available
Ratings & Reviews for this card are currently not available
Ratings & Reviews for this card are currently not available
All users of our online services subject to Privacy Statement and agree to be bound by Terms of etc...
```

How exactly do I get the rest of the visible data on this page?  Based on my research, I'm pretty sure it has to do with my parameters of soup.findAll('p')] but I don't know what to addin instead to get the rest of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching for paragraphs, get the `.text` from the `body`:

```
print(soup.body.text, file=outfile)
```

If you want to avoid `script` tag contents being written to results, you can find all tags on the top-level (see `recursive=False`) and join the text:

```
print(''.join([element.text for element in soup.body.find_all(lambda tag: tag != 'script', recursive=False)]))
```

Comment: Hi Alecx, I thought of that but that gives me ALL the data on the page, much of it useless (i.e. if(NAV==null||typeof(NAV)=="undefined"){var NAV=new Object()}NAV.RWD={body:document.getElementsByTagName) -- is  there a compromise between these two methods?

Comment: @user3682157 well, right, but you cannot easily and reliably see if an element is "visible" or not using Beautifulsoup. You can though skip "script" tags at least. Or, you can switch to selenium, which would really know what is visible and what is not.

Comment: @user3682157 I've updated the answer, included skipping `script` tag contents.