# How to Scrape HTML tags from a Website using HTMLParser

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was able to find an answer for this question in another stack overflow post, but I realize I have no idea how to actually use it.  My code ends at the print command -- everything after is what I want to use.  Can someone guide me and let me know how I can combine these two codes?  Thank you!

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ["http://www.nerdwallet.com/the-best-credit-cards"]
for url in urls:
    website = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content)
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    for item in texts:
            print(item)

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(url):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()
```

Comment: These are actually two different approaches, two different HTML Parsers. You don't need to combine them. What is your desired result? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Trying to scrape multiple websites (hence the custom function) and then get rid of every tag!  I've tried with BS but it leaves a whole bunch of tags in.  I want to only get the text from for example, that webpage.  Is the MLStripper a better approach?  I am just not really sure how to use it

Comment: The whole complete text without HTML tags? What about `script` tag content? Or, do you want the text from a part of a page, like, for example, article text, or blog post?

Comment: I just want all text -- I guess the best way to describe it would be: I want my output to look as though I copied and pasted the whole webpage manually.  Does that make sense?  I appreciate the interest

Comment: Thanks. Then, what about [the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25615925/771848) I've provided you with before?

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the previous solution.  Unfortunately, when I tried it -- it skipped over a lot of visible text on the webpage which I needed!  Any idea?  So for example this phrase: "Get cash back on eligible purchases." appears nowhere in the text doc I get.  That's why I'm trying other solutions

Comment: Hm, I actually see this text in the results. Here's [the code](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/a4e99a79f0afa60cc52b) I'm using.

Comment: copied that exact code and used it!  Still looks like I am only getting the headers?  Things like: "Entertainment and Events" or 
"Refer a Friend".  Did you check out the website I am trying to scrape.  There is a ton of text on the webpage that is missing from my output.  Not sure what to do!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60932/discussion-between-user3682157-and-alecxe).